# How to get all Conversation Email In Mail Like Windows mail App?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exchangewebservices, esb, exchange-server-2007

we are using ExchangeServiceBinding.

we want to combine emails by Conversation like Windows Mail App Do
Windows Mail App Screenshot Attached.

[Windows Mail App Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq37B.png)
Any idea about how to do it?

Comment: without database involved?

Comment: yes without database involved

Comment: in Exchange 2010 has web service features `Messaging Records Management`,
`Message Tracking (new in Exchange 2010)` I think it is possible that there is a storage of all the conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Conversation Operations GetConversationItems and FindConversations in EWS see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb409286(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: we are using 2007 Exchange server and ESB. any idea about this?

Comment: In 2007 you'll need to work with the raw properties on the items themselves read the top of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff406135(v=exchg.140).aspx.